# playing with fonts before installing them

Tags: fonts, logo, web-fonts

For a logo and website design I would like to browse and try a lot of different fonts from https://fonts.google.com or a similar site before I pick some possible candidates.

But I find it too tedious to download them, install them, restart my designer software (I'm using Sketch and Affinity Photo, Design) and then uninstall the font if it doesn't fit.

Is there a way to try those fonts immediately, before actually installing them? I just would like to quickly see certain words and text arrangements (combinations of paragraphs, headings) written in these fonts. Do you have a workflow for this, are there dedicated tool or plugins for the afore mentioned software for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to see certain words, you should be able to type into any of the font specimen examples on google fonts, then select apply to all and it will show all the fonts with those words.

Comment: But I can't for example see two styles or font sizes next to each other or how a header with a paragraph would look like.

Comment: You can open more than 1 browser window, ya know :)